# How to rename or delete a new octopress post?

Tags: octopress

Octopress provides an easy way to create a blog post using `rake new_post[title]` command. Is there a way to `rename` or `delete` the post created by the command ?

Answer (score 9):

You can just *rename* or *delete* the corresponding file in source/_post/.
If you use the common way to deploy your website (i.e. `rake deploy`), git will be used to detect the change of renaming or deleting. The update will be automatically committed without manual assistance.
However, if you use `rake rsync` to deploy website via rsync, *rsync* may have trouble detecting the renaming operation. (I guess you will not use it to introduce unnecessary inconvenience. XD)